# Im trying to make a giveaway cog using Nextcord, but I keep getting a TypeError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

So I'm trying to make a giveaway cog using Nextcord but when i try to add the button I get a error
I tried everything but still failed

This is my code:
https://pastebin.com/trD4qQTt

This is my error:
`Exception has occurred:TypeError button() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Label'`

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks!
P.S : im new to coding <:

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear: the `Label` argument doesn't exist.

You probably wanted to use the `label` argument (with a minus L)

Keep in mind that keyword arguments are usually named in [snake_case](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) in Python. Also, you can always check the [Nextcord documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html) to verify that you're using the right syntax.